# does NTP minpoll-maxpoll control sync intervals?

Tags: ntp, ntpd

Do the NTP *minpoll* and *maxpoll* configuration attributes control the sync interval or do they only control the polling interval?
where:
**polling** = messaging with NTP servers to estimate the offset
**syncing** = actually updating the system clock

Answer (score 1):

minpoll and maxpoll have to do with polling the rmote time servers. the "time synch" interval is controlled by ntpd itself. The clock adjustment algorithms are complex. More information can be found on Dr. Mills site. But the short answer is that unless you are a time wizard you do not want to be adjusting how ntpd manages clocks/drift. To be honest there are only a few situations where you should be mucking with min/max poll intervals.